# Jquery Datatables retrieving Object or Data from Ajax call. .data() returning undefined

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-ui, datatables

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tableStyle">
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">SAMPLE</h2>
            <tr>
                <th>Commands</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>PPU</th>
                <th>$ Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizeable: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    buttons: {
      Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },
      Save: function() {
        $ (this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    success: function(data) {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                data: data, 
                "pagingType": "numbers",
                'searchable': true,
                'sort': true,
                columns: [
                    {data: null,
                    defaultContent: "<button id='edit'>Edit</button> <button id='delete'>Delete</button>"
                    },
                    { data : 'id' },
                    { data : 'type' },
                    { data : 'name' },
                    { data : 'ppu' },
                    { data : 'amount',
                     render: function(amount) {
                        return '$' + amount;
                     }}
                ]
            })

            $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr #edit', function () {
                var data = table.row(this).data();
                console.log(data);
                $('#dialog h1').html("Title");
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            }); 

            $('#example tbody').on( 'click', '#delete', function () {
                alert('Delete this!');
            });
        }
    })
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is just grab the data from the associated row on the button click. I tried just about everything and everytime I try it is undefined. I'm still working on my code but this is the next part I need before I can proceed. I tried using `var data = table.row(this).data();` This returns undefined everytime. I need that associated row object by click on that specific cancel button. Once I click the button I will open a dialog box displaying certain information from that object and associated row. If anyone could help, it would a great help. 
Thanks

Comment: which browser are you using? JQuery does not work properly with Safari/Opera.

Comment: I'm using google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with the table.row( this ).data() error by first finding the index of which row I was using then passing the index through the same function.

```
var index = $(this).closest('tr').index()
var data = table.row(index).data();
```

This seemed like the easiest way to get by the problem without a big headache.